# How to popup ANY content in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, popup

Is there a right way to do this? I could not find any direct how-to for this; only gather some ideas from another kind of problems...

So my closest to this is to create a new `NSWindow` or `NSPanel`, and make it the current window's child with order Above.

But how to make it close when the user clicks off?
(This question is especially important in case this popup window does not contain any focusable controls, eg only a message or a drawing)

Is this approach a good idea anyway?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you know about the `NSPopover` class?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how could I miss this one...